# auto Renew Token in Paw

Tags: paw-app

I have the  endpoint POST /login where I send the params Form-Url encoded params email and password. The JSON Response contains the token.

Then I don't know how to tell my other Paw request, to get a valid token if needed. Because I'm not using GET as the Auth URL needs. I don't know if I need to create another endpoint and/or use ClientID  and Client Secret.  I'm missing the workflow of OAuth2 I think. Could you point to the right direction using a specific example?